# conjugates of upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

If $g \in GL_n$ is such that $gbg^{-1}$ is an upper triangular matrix for ever upper triangular matrix. Does it follow that $b$ is upper triangular? Why? Such questions just seem impossible to me because matrix multiplication is so complicated. Perhaps start by taking $b$ to be $e_{ij}$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

**Hint:** Take $g=I+e_{ij}$ where $i<j$.